Насколько целесообразно отказаться от ID в пользу hash?
Обычно, при описании сущности в БД для уникальности используется ID типа int.
А если вместо int использовать hash:
def generate_hash():
    # тут будем генерировать и возвращать hash
    ...

Base = declarative_base()

class MyModel(Base):
 __tablename__ = 'my_model'

 id = Column(String, primary_key=True, unique=True, default=generate_hash())
 ...

насколько это будет правильно: могут ли быть проблемы с производительностью и уникальностью?
Или не париться об избыточности и просто создать обычное поле ID типа int и дополнительное поле с hash, раз оно так нужно?

Правильный вопрос — а какую задачу вы решаете?

@AlexeyTen, Ну в этой таблице значения записи поля name будeт генерироваться через uuid. Таким образом получается что name можно использовать как первичный ключ. Но, потом подумал, ведь если потом сделать поиск по name(который будет hash), то наверно он будет искать дольше, чем если бы это было ID и int. Да и в интернете еще говорят что колизии м/б при генерации хеша

UUID (лучше v7) полезен когда идентификатор генерируется распределённо. Поймать коллизию в нормальной системе практически нереально. Но в вашем случае, если вы не видите явной пользы от UUID, значит её нет и не нужно усложнять себе жизнь.
